# Inequality arising when trying to show $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$ implies $\frac{a}{b+c^3}+\frac{b}{c+a^3}+\frac{c}{a+b^3}\ge\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c > 0$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$. Prove the following inequality
$$2\sum_{cyc}a^4+\sum_{cyc} ab(a^2+b^2)+8abc\sum_{cyc} a\ge 3\sum_{cyc} a^3b^3+6abc\sum _{cyc}a^2b+3abc\sum_{cyc}ab^2.$$
Maybe this paper can be  useful: [On the cyclic homogeneous polynomial inequalities of degree four](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/105_09_JIPAM/105_09_www.pdf).

The inequality arises when I solve 
$$\dfrac{a}{b+c^3}+\dfrac{b}{c+a^3}+\dfrac{c}{a+b^3}\ge\dfrac{3}{2},$$
using Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality 
$$\dfrac{a}{b+c^3}+\dfrac{b}{c+a^3}+\dfrac{c}{a+b^3}\ge\dfrac{(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ac)^2}
{a(b+c^3)(a+b)^2+b(c+a^3)(b+c)^2+c(a+b^3)(c+a)^2}$$
so that
$$\Longrightarrow  2\sum_{cyc}a^4+\sum ab(a^2+b^2)+8abc\sum a\ge 3\sum a^3b^3+6abc\sum a^2b+3abc\sum ab^2.$$

Comment: The sums are cyclic, right?

Comment: It seems your original inequality can be established if your earlier question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914594/how-prove-this-inequality-a3bb3cc3aa3b3b3c3c3a3-le-6 is shown, rather than try the long expression you have now.